# I need to connect HMA VPN using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, vpn

I like web-scraping and I did some scripts.
I come to you because I need to change my IP address using HMA VPN through python, that is, the python script is in charge of automatically connecting the vpn without having to click the connect button.
Is there a way to do that?
I have tried using "subprocess" to connect the vpn through the CMD, however it only works with vpn version 2 and I need it to work with recent versions. (https://support.hidemyass.com/hc/en-us/articles/202723586-CLI-Controlling-HMA-VPN-client-externally-with-parameters)
Feel free to ask if you need any further explanation.
I am open to hear alternatives
Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You could use browsec then control the extension as a webpage using https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/6-easy-steps-testing-your-chrome-extension-selenium to manipulate dom elements (I've successfully deployed let me know if you'd like to chat further).  this method allows you to change the country / vpn - however, lowsy speeds unless you purchase premium option;  alternative is to do above but with Windscribe - have code for that too.  nice thing is you can have multiple browsers running and each with distinct vpn/location.. not too sure about hma unfortunately but you can shuffle every x mins